# CSS - Button position in Wordpress Jquery Box

Tags: php, css, wordpress-theming

I hope you will help me again. 
Yesterday, with your help i solved my Problem with JQuery.

So my Problem is, on my Site newspace.cc under each article is a little JQuery Box which show some social share buttons.
I want to divide the Buttons (Flattr, Like, Tweet, Google Plus) correct in the Box. Because of a nice look.

But it does not start to work :(

My CSS Stylesheet: http://pastebin.de/26552
My PHP SCRIPT: http://pastebin.de/26551

So i hope you can help me. Thanks ahead !

greetz mike

Comment: If it was helpful. Please go and accept yesterday's answer which was favorable to you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you expand on what you mean by: "in the correct and perfect distance. But it does not start to work :("?

Where is it you would like them to be? Different location completely? Or just nudged in  a certain direction?

Comment: I mean, that in the Box all 4 Buttons should be divided.